# how to drive all traffic to one file with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

so I have a `slim/slim` php application and in testing I used `php -S localhost:80 -t public/` but how can I do something like this with htaccess?

Comment: heres the file tree for context. https://ibb.co/Yysh9jT

Comment: Please do not add additional information in comments. There's an "edit" button below the question. _Use it ..._

Comment: Well, you implement a single rewriting rule that catches all requests. You will find many, many existing answers to this here on SO.